# Mantaflow fire simulation has blocky rings

Tags: mantaflow

[image]

I'm curious, is the culprit of these blocky-looking flames the low resolution divisions? Or is it just a limitation in mantaflow? Currently its set to 160 and before I increase it any further, I'd like to make it look less blocky.

Edit : I found a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SMdLGKRTCzM) that shows this issue as well. He refers to it as a "steps type artifact". Any idea how to fix this?
[image]

Comment: If the sphere is the default size of 2 m in diameter, then I guess your smoke domain is quite large. In this case, 160 is a quite low resolution. When you've selected your domain, there usually is a small cube in front right bottom corner, this shows you the voxel size according to the resolution so you can see if they are too big.

Comment: Another thing is, apart from the resolution settings it would be interesting to know if you (and the creator of the video) are using Eevee or Cycles, how the material is set up, how the viewport display looks compared to the rendered image...

Comment: Alright, will do. Thanks